# How to create multi color gradient drawable with percent per color and custom angle of gradient

Tags: android, android-drawable, linear-gradients

For example I have this block from CSS:

```
.Rectangle {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #101010 30%, #151515 20%, #000000);
}
```

How can I make it on android?
One more thing. The angle value in GradientDrawable was always 45*x. How can I place it "60"?

```
<gradient android:angle="45"
              android:startColor="#101010"
              android:centerColor="#151515"
              android:endColor="#000000"
              android:centerX="0.35"
              android:centerY="1"/>
```

Comment: in android, for angle property `It must be a multiple of 45`.  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape, so I think you can not use 60

Answer (score 2):

**1 Create drawable file with Name rectangle.xml.**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <gradient android:angle="45"
        android:startColor="#101010"
        android:centerColor="#bc6767"
        android:endColor="#4068ec"
        android:centerX="0.35"
        android:centerY="1"/>
</shape>
```

Add ImageView TAG in your activity.xml

```html
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/et_age"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:hint="YEAR"
                    android:src="@drawable/rectangle"
                    android:background="@drawable/rec"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:textColor="#000" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I don't think that android:centerX="0.35" can resolve "#101010 30%, #151515 20%, #000000"